# Angular 7 - reuse component to display filtered collections

Tags: angular, web-applications, routes, router

I'm trying to develop Angular7-based web app project (online restaurant with food delivery) with MySQL database. Application is using router to navigate and load components on site.

first, an important (impacted) part of app-routing.module:

### app-routing.module.ts

```
[...]  
{
path: 'menu',
component: MenuComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'categories',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  },
  {
    path: 'categories',
    component: ProductCategoriesComponent,
    resolve: {
      productCategories: CategoriesResolver,
      products: ProductsResolve
    },
  },
  {
    path: 'categories/:id',
    component: ProductsByCategoryComponent,
    resolve: {
      productsByCategory: ProductsResolveByCategory,
      productCategories: CategoriesResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'categories',
    pathMatch: 'prefix'
  }
],
  },
[...]
```

**Use-case scenario is as follows:
I. User clicks "Menu" navlink on navbar - menu component is being loaded:
url path after action: localhost:4200/menu/categories/ **

### menu-component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this is just placeholder to load categories of products offered by menu - Angular redirects the user to menu/categories and is loading ProductCategoriesComponent. This one uses two resolvers - to actually resolve all categories of products, and all products (they are all loaded since no specific category has been selected).

The category IDs are as follows:
1 - appetizers
2 - pizza
3 - pasta
4 - drinks
5 - desserts

** II. After user selects a specific category, the whole list is being filtered and backend returns new list of objects with requested categoryId: **

### product.resolve.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsResolveByCategory implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.productService.getProductsByCategoryId(route.params['id']);
  }
}
```

the routing leads us to for example: localhost:4200/menu/categories/1 when "appetizers" category has been selected.

So far app was working so good, but a problem with displaying content on specific conditions appeared - when user is on /menu/categories/1 and wants to choose another category (change from 1 to 2 for example), the view is not refreshing itself - no products with different category id are being loaded, we can still see old ones - for the moment the workaround is to click the menu button again, then desired category. What's more, clicking "back" in browser (so it should return to menu/categories/) throws a bad request (error 400), as frontend sends request with /menu/categories/categories (double!) instead of 'id'. I can't find any logical explanation why 'id' gets replaced by 'categories' word:

### products.service.ts

```
  public getProductsByCategoryId(id: number): Observable<Array<ProductModel>> {
   return this.http.get('/api/products/categories/' + id).pipe(map((response: Array<ProductModel>) => {
   this.productsByCategory = response;
   return this.productsByCategory;
 }));
}
```

### products-by-category.component.ts

```
 Component({
  selector: 'app-products-by-category',
  templateUrl: './products-by-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./../products/products.component.css'],
})
export class ProductsByCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  private productsByCategory: Array<ProductModel> = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

   ngOnInit() {
     if (this.route.snapshot.data['productsByCategory']) {
       this.productsByCategory = this.route.snapshot.data['productsByCategory'];
     }
   }
}
```

So to sum up, there are two (most likely stupid mistakes in logic) problems:

1. Why when changing from menu/categories/1 to menu/categories/2, the proper items are not being loaded,
2. Why when navigatng back to /menu/categories/, the frontend sends /menu/categories/categories/ instead of /menu/categories/ - as the 'id' variable, it sends 'categories' word... (this issue happens as well when user removes /1 from end of the link in browser)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to consume updates in your component you should subscribe to data, instead of accessing it through snapshot. Instead of `this.route.snapshot.data['productsByCategory']` use `this.route.data.subscribe((data) => { this.productsByCategory = data['productsByCategory'];})`.
to fix the second issue remove `path: ''` config from router configuration. I think that will be enough, as `path: '**'` config already handles that case.

Comment: Splendid! both problems has been fixed b the solutions you provided. Thanks for clear and fast response!